# Can't update the related table on prisma

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

First of all this is my `schema.prisma` file. The problem is when i try to update a payment to complete and then update the wallet value in the same query.

```js
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  uid         String    @id @default(cuid())
  created_at  DateTime
  username    String
  roles       String[]
  accessToken String
  session     Session[]
  walletId    String    @unique
  wallet      Wallet    @relation(fields: [walletId], references: [id])
  payment     Payment[]
}

model Session {
  id       String   @id @default(uuid())
  userid   String
  expires  DateTime @db.Timestamptz
  cookieId String   @unique
  user     User     @relation(fields: [userid], references: [uid])
}

model Wallet {
  id      String    @id @default(uuid())
  balance Int       @default(0)
  user    User?
  payment  Payment[]
}

model Order {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  product   Product  @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id]) //Note that only one product can be ordered at a time
  payment   Payment  @relation(fields: [paymentId], references: [piPaymentId])
  productId String
  paymentId String   @unique
}

model Payment {
  piPaymentId String        @id @unique
  amount      Float
  txid        String        @default("")
  status      PaymentStatus @default(PENDING)
  user        User          @relation(fields: [userId], references: [uid])
  order       Order?
  wallet      Wallet        @relation(fields: [walletId], references: [id])
  walletId    String
  userId      String
}

model Product {
  id     String  @id @default(uuid())
  name   String
  price  Float
  amount Int //Note at this moment we only support coins as a product
  order  Order[]
}

enum PaymentStatus {
  PENDING
  PAID
  FAILED
  CANCELLED
}
```

First I create a new payment with any problems:

```js
  async create(payment: APIRequests.Paymnet.Create) {
    return await this.db.prisma.payment.create({
      data: {
        piPaymentId: payment.paymentId,
        user: {
          connect: {
            uid: payment.userId,
          },
        },
        amount: payment.amount,
        status: "PENDING",
        wallet: {
          connect: {
            id: payment.walletId
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

And then after some events in the backend i need to update the state of the payment as PAID and update the user's wallet as well.

```js
async complete(payment: APIRequests.Paymnet.Complete) {
    await this.db.prisma.payment.update({
      where: {
        piPaymentId: payment.paymentId
      },
      data: {
        status: "PAID",
        txid: payment.txid,
        wallet: {
          update: {
            balance: {
              decrement: payment.amount
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

the problem is here when I try to execute this query i get this error message...

```
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.payment.update()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    piPaymentId: 'some paymentID'
  },
  data: {
    status: 'PAID',
    txid: 'some txid',
    wallet: {
    ~~~~~~
      update: {
        balance: {
          decrement: 0.1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Unknown arg `wallet` in data.wallet for type PaymentUncheckedUpdateInput. Did you mean `walletId`? Available args:   
type PaymentUncheckedUpdateInput {
  piPaymentId?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  amount?: Float | FloatFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  txid?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  status?: PaymentStatus | EnumPaymentStatusFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  order?: OrderUncheckedUpdateOneWithoutPaymentNestedInput
  walletId?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  userId?: String | StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your schema.prisma, try to add one more line as below:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["views"]  // add this line
}
```

It works for me. Here is the reference document (https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/views)